# Java LongAdder sumThenReset Concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency

I am considering switching to using LongAdder from AtomicLong. I'm using it for counting requests reaching a server, and every 1 minute I write the result to a DB and start counting again. For that sake I used AtomicLong's *getAndSet* method, which I intend to replace with *sumThenReset* of LongAdder.

The documentation of *sumThenReset* states the following:

> the returned value is not guaranteed to be the final value occurring before the reset

So what have we done here? Does it mean that some increments can by definition be lost and not counted anywhere?

Comment: If contention is a problem you could instead save the latest total and log the delta to the current total. No lost updates, works after restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the whole method doc:

> This method may apply for example during quiescent points between
>   multithreaded computations. If there are updates concurrent with this
>   method, the returned value is not guaranteed to be the final value
>   occurring before the reset.

Quiescent means to quiet. That is, no threads are updating the LongAdder. So to answer your question, yes some increments may be lost.

From the Class doc:

> This class is usually preferable to AtomicLong when multiple threads
>   update a common sum that is used for purposes such as collecting
>   statistics, not for fine-grained synchronization control.

Probably what you need is AtomicLong.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that if you extend the implementation of sumAndReset to do:

```
long sum = longAdder.sum();<br>
longAdder.add(-sum);<br>
return sum;
```

It works very nicely.
The reason is because the implementation behind the scene breaks up the storage into a number of cells. So the number of actual atomic adds are significantly reduced. So it is optimized for atomic adds. The sum, reset, and sumAndReset iterate over the cells and sum or reset or both and as such are not atomic. So instead using a negative add works very well. because you remove exactly what you summed, and return only that much as such maintain the over all counts.

Comment: This solves the issue if there are concurrent calls to `add()` when you try to `sumAndReset()`, but it's still not enough if there are concurrent calls to `sumAndReset()`. Making it `synchronized` could be a sensible solution assuming the high contention is only on the calls to `add()`.